# Creating regex to match whole string and can be repetitive

Tags: javascript, angular, regex

I have some combinations of city and country code which can be one or more and city is a free text so it can be anything. I have tried javascript regex to match but somehow it fails in some context. So for example

Valid Strings:

```
 1. City name(IN)
 2. ,,cityname      (US)
 3. abc ebj - fsh (IN)
 4. def_fgi(US), Another city(IN), more,city,name (Uk)
 5. random characters -233,df.adf (GF)
```

Invalid Strings:

```
 1. Cityname
 2. (IN)
 3. abc(US),          (IN)
 4. abc(US),(UK)
```

what I have tried is something like

```
step 1. it should start with (space or coma) - with optional tag ([\s,]+)?
step 2. then it should look for atleast 1 character except bracket ([^\(]{1,})
step 3. then it will look for a opening bracket 
step 4. then 2 length string ([A-Z]{2})
step 5. then closing bracket
step 6. at end it can repeat from step to 5 as optional tag of ?

/^(([\s,]+)?([^\(]{1,})\(([A-Z]{2})\))+$/
```

but it fails to hold coma for something like abc (DE), (FG) - it shows as valid

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your rules and examples are contradictory; the 5th invalid string follows the same pattern as the 5th valid string.

Comment: @fortran it does not.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan mind to explain how are they different?

Comment: @fortran `3,d` vs `y, m` notice the space

Comment: I see. Well, it is still contradictory in other cases. That implies that the separator is comma plus some whitespace; so the fourth _invalid_ example is actually valid because it means the city is named "abc(US)," and the country code is "(UK)"

Comment: No that's my bad, yes 5th invalid will be valid one. Thank you RokoC.Buljan and fortran. I have removed it from invalid category.

Comment: @fortran The separator is simply a bracket ( between a country and city. User can input any number of spaces in between so that needs to be a optional check.

Comment: So now are you sure `,,cityname  (HR)` is valid? With those leading commas?

Comment: yes @RokoC.Buljan it will be valid as before ( is city and between (country ). But here is the catch . If it is multiple entries so it can be also . 
,, city1(HR),,,,city2(HR),        ,,,city3(HR), city,4(HR)

Comment: (Uk) will not match (since not two uppercase characters) but you inserted it as valid string. Try not to be sloppy when asking precise regex questions.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan anything between () will be checked for 2 letters and is country, case is not a mandatory thing. so (Uk) is valid also.

Comment: @Luckyy then do `[a-zA-Z]` in your regex instead of `[A-Z]`; or it becomes confusing

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve it with a big regex, but it's easier if you do it in two steps:

```js
function validateChunk(chunk) {
  //anything followed by a country code
  return chunk.match(/^.+\([a-zA-Z]{2}\)$/);
}

function validate(text) {
  //separator is comma followed by whitespace
  const chunks = text.split(/,\s+/);
  return chunks.every(validateChunk);
}

for (sample of [
'City name(IN)',
',,cityname      (US)',
'abc ebj - fsh (IN)',
'def_fgi(US), Another city(IN), more,city,name (Uk)',
'random characters -233,df.adf (GF)',
'Cityname',
'(IN)',
'abc(US),          (IN)',
'abc(US),(UK)',
'somecity, more (IN)',
]) {
  console.log(validate(sample), '\t', sample);
};
```

Note that `'abc(US),(UK)'` is considered valid because with your rules `abc(US),` is a valid city name followed by the country code `(UK)`. If you want that to fail, change `validateChunk` so the first part is `[^()]+` instead of `.+` and prevent city names to contain parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

For the given example data, you might use a case insensitive match matching optional spaces and comma's at the start and end.

Match at least a part with 2 chars a-z between parenthesis where there is at least a word character before it.

```
^[ ,]*(?:[^()\n]*\w[^()\n]*\([A-Z]{2}\))+[ ,]*$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `[ ,]*` Optionally repeat matching a comma or space
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[^()\n]*\w[^()\n]*` Match a single word char between any char except parenthesis or a newline at the left and right of the word char
  - `\([A-Z]{2}\)` Match 2 chars a-zA-Z between parenthesis
- `)+` Close the non capture group and repeat 1 or more times
- `[ ,]*` Optionally repeat matching a comma or space
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mZRKka/1)

```js
const regex = /^[ ,]*(?:[^()\n]*\w[^()\n]*\([A-Z]{2}\))+[ ,]*$/i;
["City name(IN)",
  ",,cityname      (US)",
  "abc ebj - fsh (IN)",
  "def_fgi(US), Another city(IN), more,city,name (Uk)",
  "random characters -233,df.adf (GF)",
  ",, city1(HR),,,,city2(HR), ,,,city3(HR), city,4(HR)",
  ",,cityname  (HR)",
  " Cityname",
  " (IN)",
  " abc(US),          (IN)",
  " abc(US),(UK)"
].forEach(s => console.log(`${regex.test(s)} --> ${s}`));
```

Comment: Thank you it works in most cases perfectly  but it is failing in one case - where user has entered city name as commas so - ,,, (US), ,,,(UK) should be valid and ,,, will be city names here

Comment: @Luckyy You might use an alternation to match 2 or more comma's `^(?:[ ,]*(?:[^()\n]*\w[^()\n]*|,{2,}) *\([A-Z]{2}\))+[ ,]*$` https://regex101.com/r/tW9HGn/1

Comment: @Luckyy You could also rule out parts that should not be matched `^(?=.*\([A-Za-z]{2}\))(?!(?:.*(?<!,),)? *\([A-Za-z]{2}\)).+` https://regex101.com/r/2WZs86/1

Comment: Makes absolutely no sense to use `,,,,,,,,,,` as a name. I think you're fighting the wrong beast. Such stuff should be better handled upfront.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan You are right about that. I tried creating a solution for the given example data. Then there was an edge case, and to account for that edge case strange matches can appear :-)